# How to pass a string value to firebase child( )?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It works like this:

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child(document.getElementById("areaCode").value);
```

Or any suggestions to pass `x` like this:

```
var areaCodex = document.getElementById("areaCode");
var x = areaCodex.toString();
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child(x);

$('#saveBtn').click(function() {
  rootRef.set({
    date: $('#date').val(),
    timeF: $('#fromTime').val()
  });
})
```

I need to save data to Firebase and my code is as follows:

```
var toTime = document.getElementById("toTime");
var areaCode = document.getElementById("areaCode"); 

function submitClick(){
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child();//here in .child() i need to pass the areaCode as an argument. It works when i hardcode a value like .child('1234'). But i need that to be what ever the value I am getting from the textbox of areaCode. I have tried //var x = areaCode.value; // var y = x.toString and var y = String(x); , trying to pass y as .child(y) 
// also var y = areaCode.toString(); does not work.

    var toTimeText = toTime.value;
    firebaseRef.child("toTime").set(toTimeText);

    window.confirm("Data has been successfully sent.");

}
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function sumbitClick(){
var toTimeText = document.getElementById("toTime").value;
var ref = firebase.database().ref(path_to_your_child);

        ref.once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
         ref.set(toTimeText);
      });
}
```

Comment: remember this code should be in some <script> tag in the END of the HTML document, so it will load first all your DOM and then get the value of the input. like this --> 1.open <script> tag 2.add event listener and callback submitClick() 3.place this code 4. close </script>

Comment: Hello, Antonio Thanx for answering. Here what is the .ref(path_to_your_child); ?

Comment: My first node is the area code. Under that I need to have the toTime value